# Isotope: Adding different sized elements with ajax(isotope reorders everything)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a list with elements positioned with isotopes. When i scroll to the bottom, i add several more items. The problem however is that the elements that are already there try to relayout with the ones being added. This causes newly added items to be randomly places in the list(could end up on top).

This is kinda stupid since the user wont know what was actually added.

This is what i'm using to add the new items atm. (This is adding the elements, but now how i want it too)

```
                var di = $(html);
                $("#container").isotope('insert', di);
                $("#container").isotope();
```

Is there any other way? I've tried using 'appended', but it seems to fail.

```
            var di = $(html);
            $("#container").append(di).isotope('appended', di);
            $("#container").isotope();
```

This is the errormessage i get:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined [http://localhost:5440/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:6948]

Comment: What about using subcontainer and apply isotope to only last added subcontainer

Comment: This works. However, i would like the added items to stay inside the same already existing container so it fills up empty space at the end of the previous container.

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue and maybe someone would be glad to help you